# Improve an subroutine fortran

Tags: fortran, lapack

I built a subroutine in Fortran and it is working fine and correctly but it is taking longer than it should.

Any ideia to how can I improve this subroutine?
Maybe modifying how the parameters are declared or taking out some unnecessary `do`.

`ZGESV` and `ZGEEV` are subroutines from Lapack to solve linear complex systems (for example: A*x=B).

```
Subroutine arnoldi(m,n,A,B,sigma,eig,INFO)
implicit none

integer, intent(in) :: n, m
integer, intent(out)    :: INFO
complex(8), intent(in)  :: sigma
complex(8), dimension(m), intent(out)   :: eig
complex(8), dimension(n,n), intent(in)  :: A,B

! Argumentos
integer :: i, j, LDVL, LDVR, one
integer ::  LWORK
integer, dimension(n) :: IPIV
complex(8), dimension(n) :: r, q
complex(8), dimension(n,n) :: C
complex(8), dimension (m,m) :: VL,VR 
complex(8), dimension(6*(m+1)) :: WORK
complex(8), dimension(m+1,m) :: h
complex(8), dimension(n,m+1) :: v
complex(8), dimension(m,m) :: hh
real(8), dimension(8*(m+1)) :: RWORK
character :: JOBVL, JOBVR

! Lapack
JOBVL = 'N'
JOBVR = 'N'
LWORK = 6*(m+1) 
LDVL = 2*(m+1)
LDVR = 2*(m+1)
one = 1

! Arnoldi
q = dcmplx(1.0d0,0.0d0)
q = q/norm2(zabs(q))
v(:,1) = q

C = A - sigma*B

do i = 1,m

    r = Matmul(B,v(:,i))

    CALL ZGESV(n,one,C,n,IPIV,r,n,INFO)

    do j = 1,i
            h(j,i) = dot_product(v(:,j),r)
            r = r - v(:,j)*h(j,i)
    end do

    if (i.lt.n) then 
            h(i+1,i) = norm2(zabs(r))
        if (zabs(h(i+1,i)).lt.1.0d-7) exit
            v(:,i+1) = r/h(i+1,i)
    end if

end do



do i = 1,m

    do j = 1,m
            HH(i,j) = h(i,j)
    end do

end do

CALL ZGEEV(JOBVL,JOBVR,m,HH,m,eig,VL,LDVL,VR,LDVR,WORK,LWORK,RWORK,INFO)

! Autovalores
do i=1,m
   eig(i) = dcmplx(1.0d0,0.0d0)/eig(i) + sigma
end do

end subroutine
```

Comment: Howw long does it take and how long "should" it take? How do you compile? How much of the time does each of the do loops take? How much of the overall time does the LAPACK call ZGEEV take? Note that using a literal kind 8 is an ugy code smell and is not portable.

Comment: Also note things like dcmplx and (the non-standard) zabs should not be used and instead use the generic cmplx, and abs - and learn about kinds properly so you can use cmplx appropriately and avoid d0 and similar.

Comment: use ddot instead of your own dot_product, make HH = h instead of your m^2 loop.